# Logging handlers disappears when I try to get a child logger with Logger.getChild() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a root logger with some handlers on it (SysLogHandler lets say).

And I want to get a child logger from the root logger by calling the  `Logger.getChild(__name__)`, but when I do so, I got the new logger with no handlers on it. What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

```py
import logging
from logging import handlers


sysh = handlers.SysLogHandler()

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(sysh)
logger.handlers  # [<SysLogHandler (NOTSET)>] - everything is ok

c = logger.getChild('some_name')
c.handlers  # []  where is the handler(SysLogHandler) from parent(root) logger???
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getChild`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1647) does the same thing that [`logging.getLogger`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1932) does. Both call the [`getLogger`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1216) method on the [`logging.Manager`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1200) instance.
The manager either returns an existing logger that has been registered in its `loggerDict` attribute or instantiates a new logger, registers and returns it. In the latter case, the new logger must be configured by the caller.

[`getChild`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getChild) is not meant to create a clone of the logger it was called on. It is intended as

> [...] a convenience method, useful when the parent logger is named using
>   e.g. `__name__` rather than a literal string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm interested in getting the handlers that are assigned to the root logger? Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: @Dinsultan I guess you can always go for: `c.handlers = logger.handlers` or, slightly more verbose and preserves dedicated handlers that you might have added before: `for handler in logger.handlers: c.handlers.append(handler)`. Beware though, this creates duplicate log events if the child is set to [`propagate=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) (the default).

Comment: Oh, or `for handler in logger.handlers: c.addHandler(handler)`, of course.